# How to fix the domain violation error in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

when i run this code it shows domain violation error for element, how do i remove the error.?

```
...

table data (i, coef)
    a        b    c
1   0.0016   2    0
2   0.01     2.5  0
3   0.0625   1.0  0
4   0.00834  3.25 0
5   0.025    3    0
6   0.025    3    0;
table Losscoef(i,j)
   1         2          3           4          5          6
1  0.000218  0.000103   0.000009   -0.00001    0.000002   0.000027
2  0.000103  0.000181   0.000004   -0.000015   0.000002   0.00003
3  0.000009  0.000004   0.000417   -0.000131  -0.000153  -0.000107
4 -0.00014  -0.000015  -0.000131    0.000221   0.000094   0.00005
5  0.000002  0.000002  -0.000153    0.000094   0.000243   0
6  0.000027  0.00003   -0.000107    0.00005    0          0.000358;

...
```

Comment: Need more code or the ``.lst`` output to work it out. At first pass, it suggests you haven't defined one (or more) of the sets ``i``, ``coef``, or ``j`` with the elements you are using in the tables. Where is the error showing up in the ``.lst`` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No error now, you must first de-clear your sets

```
set i /1*6/
coef /a,b,c/;
alias(i,j);

table data (i, coef)
    a        b    c
1   0.0016   2    0
2   0.01     2.5  0
3   0.0625   1.0  0
4   0.00834  3.25 0
5   0.025    3    0
6   0.025    3    0;

table Losscoef(i,j)
   1         2          3           4          5          6
1  0.000218  0.000103   0.000009   -0.00001    0.000002   0.000027
2  0.000103  0.000181   0.000004   -0.000015   0.000002   0.00003
3  0.000009  0.000004   0.000417   -0.000131  -0.000153  -0.000107
4 -0.00014  -0.000015  -0.000131    0.000221   0.000094   0.00005
5  0.000002  0.000002  -0.000153    0.000094   0.000243   0
6  0.000027  0.00003   -0.000107    0.00005    0          0.000358;
```